# Identify version of Edge WebView

Tags: webview, office-js, microsoft-edge, word-addins

We are working on an Office 365 Office JS Word Add-in.

How to identify Edge WebView version (i.e. Legacy Edge WebView or Edge WebView2)?

I couldn't find any documentation related to it.

Querying userAgent gives below details.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; WebView/3.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.18363`

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the userAgent , I think it should be Legacy Edge WebView.

[Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2) is using Microsoft Edge (Chromium) as the rendering engine. The [userAgent of Microsoft Edge Chromium](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-string) should be like this:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.116 Safari/537.36 Edg/80.0.361.57"
```

This format is the same as the Chromium UA with the addition of a new `Edg` token at the end, but Microsoft Edge based on EdgeHTML uses `Edge`.

Comment: Seems the user agent for Edge Browser Chromium and Edge WebView2 Chromium is the same. Any chance to differentiate the client?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I can answer now since none was accepted. You the user agent will contain "WebView/3.0" when it is a WebView2.

Comment: What do you mean by "you the user agent"?